# Cordova Camera custom image width and height

Tags: cordova

My app use the Cordova camera plugin to capture image using the device default camera, but the image taken is too high, and I only want an image's height to be half of the screen, is there a way to custom the target height? I tried using targetHeight and targetWidth in the options parameter, but nothing changes.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this:-

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, 
  { quality : 25,
  destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
  allowEdit : true,
  encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  targetWidth: 512,
  targetHeight: 512,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: true 
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work, as this opens the photo edit window to crop the image, but when the cropping is done, the onSuccess function still returns the original long image, any idea?